# Rails: text_filed_tag with attribute condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have for example this input

```
 <%= text_field_tag :price, params[:price] %>
```

it is possible if `params[:something]==true` add to that text_field_tag `:disabled=>true` tag ?

I know i can

```
<% if params[:something]=="true" %>
  <%= text_field_tag :price, params[:price] %>
<% else %>
  <%= text_field_tag :price, params[:price], :disabled=>true %>
<% end %>
```

but if i have 10 textboxes its not nice :-)

I tried

```
<%= text_field_tag :price, params[:price] (params['something']=="true" ?, :disabled=>true : "") %>
```

but that as other attempts does not work :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

This should work

```
<%= text_field_tag :price, params[:price], readonly: (readonly ? true : false) %>
```

Comment: i have `<%= text_field_tag :price, params[:price], :readonly=>true if readonly %>` if readonly is true its disabled properly but if readonly is false it dont display anything ?:P (i believe because of comma separator ',')

Comment: @Muflix  what if?
<%= text_field_tag :price, params[:price], readonly: (readonly ? true : false) %>